# Abort insert ... select clause

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

Is it possible to abort an insert ... select clause from Java ? Using either JDBC or Hibernate, it doesn't matter. The DB is Oracle.

I reckon it's not possible because there is a single DB call and the process is running in Oracle, not the JVM.

Comment: It **is** possible! Look at the `Statement` class. There is a method to cancel the execution of a query: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#cancel()

Answer (score 1):

Oracle OCI (C driver) provides an `OCIBreak()` function. It's even thread-safe and you can call it from any bg thread, while the main thread is using the same connection.

Maybe that `Statement.cancel()` does the same thing.

This `OCIBreak()` requires round trip to DB server (i.e. the network must be functional) and then the main thread receives an error:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation

You should be able to mark this exception as non-critical on JBOSS level (using `ExceptionSorter`).

PS: I'm really curious if this could be called from hibernate. As JPA leaves many long running queries on our DB servers.